# Team Foundation Server Read Only Rights?

Tags: tfs

I cant seem to find where to set read only rights for users within TFS when viewing test items/cases and plans. So if a test case is opened a user shouldn't be able to edit the case. Any idea? TIA

Answer (score 0):

You control work item permissions at the [area path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations) level.